# Angular8 - [tinymce] library - editor element and setting multiline

Tags: angular, typescript, tinymce

I'm using Angular 8 and in template we have something like that:

```
<editor
              required
              class="research-modal__control__input research-modal__control__input__description"
              formControlName="description"
              id="description"
              [inline]="false" //my attempt
              placeholder="Description"
              [init]="{
                      base_url: '/tinymce',
                      suffix: '.min',
                      inline: true,
                      height: 500,
                      menubar: false,
                      toolbar:
                        'subscript superscript'
                    }"
            ></editor>
```

Anybody knows how to set multiline mode?
For example when I enter in this textarea field something like:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

and in database (Postgres) there is saved value with end lines, then after reopening my popup window with  tag, everything is displayed in one line:

```
line1 line2 line3
```

I can't find solution in Internet... How can I enable multiline?

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE is an HTML editor - as such the content you load into the editor should be valid HTML.  If you just pass a string of plain text with no markup TinyMCE will wrap it in a single block element (`<p>...</p>`).  Carriage Returns and Line Breaks have no meaning in HTML so they are ignored/removed.

Comment: Hmm ok so what solution do you propose? After typing some rows with break line maybe should I intercept the text and replace newline chars with for example <br\> and that structure save in database?

Comment: That would work as would converting each line to its own paragraph.  Using `br` tags leaves the entire item as a single block element which will impact certain behaviors in the editor (vs making each line its own paragraph).  It is really up to you to determine what is appropriate for your use case.